# Remove RAID metadata from HDD so it can be repurposed as a single disk

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm, fdisk, qnap

Previous RAID config was RAID6 in a QNAP NAS, I now want to repurpose the disks as 8 individual disk in different machines.

Each disk appears to have some RAID metadata (superblock) that is stopping me format them to the full capacity (3TB).

I've tried :

```
sudo mdadm -v --zero-superblock /dev/sdb

mdadm: Unrecognised md component device - /dev/sdb


sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1565565868 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

So not really sure what to do now. I basically want clear everything off each disk.

Also not sure it's relevant but I only have access to each disk via a USB 2.0 caddy.

Also tried Diskpart and no luck

[image: diskpart]

Comment: "I basically want clear everything off each disk." – Do you mean *everything*? (so each disk is totally clean). Or (per title) metadata? (so the disk *looks* clean but data recovery tools are able to find something).

Comment: You have a mix of Linux-like device names and then "Microsoft" appearing next... which OS is it where you intend to clear the disks?

Comment: @Hannu The disk were pulled from QNAP. I have them in a USB caddy. I can access this caddy from my Windows 11 OS.  I also have VMWARE installed with a Ubtuntu VM which i can also access the caddy. This is the reason you see both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I basically want to format then to 3TB and then use them again sometime or donate to my friends. Just want them useable

Comment: In Linux: [`wipefs -a`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/wipefs.8.html).

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=746GB

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, I think that is the issue - thankyou. I'll connect via SATA rather than USB and see how I get on. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Important: make sure you are 100% sure about the device name for the disk; you do NOT want to do this on a "live" disk *(i.e. one you wish to go on using)*.

```
$ lsblk
```

Will tell which disks you have available currently; i suggest to run it BEFORE you connect the "USB-caddy", and then just after connecting, probing the difference between those two runs.

To actually clear the disk partitioning info, normally you may erase content info (metadata) with:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 /dev/sdb
```

IF the actual USB-caddy does appear as `/dev/sbd` - ***in the second `lsblk` run (above)***.
NOTE: This is for standard GPT or MBR formatted disks, I cannot tell for other partitioning formats.

Comment: At the same time I had just executed `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M` which is pretty much the same as your suggestion. I'll let you now how i get on

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1

1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.761137 s, 1.4 MB/s` and it  made no difference, still reports at 746GB

Comment: @molko `sudo partprobe`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thans, just tired that and it's the same - `Disk /dev/sdb: 746.52 GiB, 801569724928 bytes, 1565565869 sectors
Disk model: EFRX-68EUZN0 ` you can see the Disk Model refers to a WesterDigital 3TB device

Comment: Another try: Get / Create e.g. "Ubuntu Linux" Install media and boot it in "Try Ubuntu"-mode, then check if e.g. "gparted" can null out the partitioning info, or even try the "dd" thing from there too (Thinking: Remove "Windows" from having control over writes).